# How do I change the default version of python used by virtualenv?

Tags: python, virtualenv

`virtualenv` when running on my computer is not using the verison of `python3` that I expect. I want it to use the same version as that returned by `which python` - is there a way of changing the default version of python that virtualenv uses.

I can use the `-p` [flag](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/virtualenv.1.html) in a particular invocation, but I can't find a way of changing the default in the man page.

There is an obvious terrible work around with [bash aliases](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-create-bash-aliases/) but this is terrible.

Comment: Does `$(which python) -m venv .venv` do what you want? As I remember it was recommended to create virtualenvs by running them as script with desired python. So even just `python -m venv .venv` should do the job.

Comment: That does indeed work... unfortunately I'm not calling `virtualenv` myself - emacs is through `python-virtualenv`...

Answer (score 1):

virtualenv defaults to the python it was run with.  I do this on my machine with ... more virtualenvs!

step 1: create a virtualenv at a ~well known location in your home directory.  I use `~/opt/venv`.  make sure to use the python you want to be the default (in my case, `python3.9`)

```
virtualenv ~/opt/venv -p python3.9
```

step 2: install virtualenv into that virtualenv

```
~/opt/venv/bin/pip install virtualenv
```

step 3: put that `virtualenv` onto your `PATH` (for example, I have `~/bin` on the path, you might have `~/.local/bin` or some other directory

```
ln -s ~/opt/venv/bin/virtualenv ~/bin/
```

now when you make virtualenvs, it will use this executable and default to the python you picked

```
$ which virtualenv
/home/asottile/opt/venv/bin/virtualenv
```

Comment: Thanks for that... I wonder why `virtualenv` is pointing at an old version of python on my machine.

Comment: `pip3 install virtualenv` on my box seems to have upgraded the virtualenv on my path so that it points the new version of python.